# Select from two entities with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

I have some issues wrapping my head around the .include in LINQ. I'd appreciate a lot if someone could show me the query to achieve this:

I have two entities, User and Validation (which is a serie of validation codes) . They are related in EF5 as 1:*. I'm trying to get a User object and eager load the Validations collection.

At this moment, I'm doing this (cx being the Context inside a using block):

```
var user = cx.Users
            .Where(u => u.UserGuid.Equals(UserGuid))
            .FirstOrDefault();

if (user == null)
{
    return 0;
}

var validation = cx.Validations
            .Where(v => v.Code.Equals(Code))
            .Where(v => v.UserId.Equals(user.UserId))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But how do I achieve this in only one query so that then I can use

```
user.Validations.FirstOrDefault();
```

without getting an error and by only getting the Validations that satisfy the Validation.Code == Code test?

Thanks for your help (I know I'm sounding confused but that's because I am).

Comment: have you tried `user.Validations.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Code.Equals(Code));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
var validation = cx.Validations.Where(v=>v.Code==Code &&
                                         cx.Users.Any(u=>u.UserID==v.UserID && 
                                                         u.UserGuid==UserGuid)
                                      ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to include the related records as well by doing:

```
var user = cx.Users
             .Where(u => u.UserGuid.Equals(UserGuid))
             .Include(u => u.Validations)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

but then you should be able to select the requested validaiton with

```
user.Validations
    .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Code.Equals(Code));
```